# jstree node name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

This is the data format for my nodes:

```
{
data: "new Structure",
attr: {id:"1", class:"structureNode", rel:"root"}
}
```

I have a reference for the node in question, and I can easily get the attributes

```
nodeReference.attr('attributeName')
```

However, I can't get access to the node name, stored in "data". Is there any way to get access to this while having a node reference (other than searching through the DOM to find the text in the `<a>` field, which I find very cumbersome)?

I've considered storing the name in the attr array as well, but I don't like to have redundancy.

Thanks :-)

Comment: Do you mean the link description between <a> and </a>?

Comment: Yeah, the node name is between <a> and </a> in the document, but I feel like there should be a way to access the data of the node when I have a reference for it.

Comment: Have you already tried the method '.data' from standard dom (or standard javascript)? It looks like "nodeReference.data".

Comment: Yeah, tried that. That just returns the jQuery data function:

function (key, value) {
    var data = null;
    if (typeof key === "undefined") {
        if (this.length) {
            data = jQuery.data(this[0]);
...

etc

Comment: without any example is hardly possible to make any soloution

Comment: I don't understand what other information you would need? I can access all the attributes using the example I provided, but I don't have a way to access the "data" field. nodeReference.data didn't work, as that just gave me the functions available with jQuery .data().

My question is just basically: Is there a way to access a jstree node's "data" field, in the same was as its "attr" field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution in the documentation. Apparently, all you need is `.get_text(nodeReference)` :-)

Comment: You're right. The function is document here: http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core#get_text